# PHP how to read info from text file that is not always properly formatted and generate script

Tags: php, text, directory, auto-generate

I maintain a website at work for a client that was very badly created by someone else, and a new one from scratch is not an option, it's becoming really frustrating and time consuming so I'm looking to automate the process by reading the file with PHP and auto generating the script.

I get a text file with some information that is not always the same format, here is an example:

```
DIV 054  Size: 50-18-135



*** Col-Gold/Ivory

Col-Brown

Col-Pink



Frame Measurement: A-50 B-27



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)





DIV 1024 Size: 53-16-135



*** Col-Gunmetal

Col-Brown



Frame Measurement: A-52 B-30



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 1046 Size: 53-16-135



*** Col-Purple/Pink

Col-Brown/Cream



Frame Measurement: A-53 B-37



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 1049 Size: 58-17-140



*** Col-Black/Gun

Col-Bronze/Gold



Frame Measurement: A-57 B-35



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 1056 Size: 52-17-135



*** Col-Brown

Col-Gold/Ivory



Frame Measurement: A-52 B-30



DIV 1057 Size: 51-17-135



*** Col-Pink

Col-Gold



Frame Measurement: A-51 B-31



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 1063 Size: 54-17-140



*** Col-Blue/Silver

Col-Gunmetal/Black



Frame Measurement: A-54 B-34



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 1073 Size: 54-16-138



*** Col-Pink

Col-Gold/Brown



Frame Measurement: A-54 B-36



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 2065 Size: 52-18-137



*** Col-Gold/Silver

Col-Pink/Silver



Frame Measurement: A-52 B-31



DIV 2149 Size: 57-17-145



*** Col-Black

Col-Gunmetal



Frame Measurement: A-57 B-35



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 2153 Size: 52-18-135



*** Col-Pink

Col-Brown/Ivory



Frame Measurement: A-52 B-36



DIV 4067 Size: 54-16-135



*** Col-Demi-Brown

Col-Black



Frame Measurement: A-52 B-39



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)



DIV 4071 Size: 53-15-138



*** Col-Purple/Pink

Col-Black/Red



Frame Measurement: A-53 B-39



(Upper right hand corner “w/ spring hinges”)
```

Some notes:

- The DIV xxx is a model number, both "DIV" and xxx may change The
- col-color sometimes comes in 1-4 variations (so some items have 1 color, others have up to 4)
- I get a folder with images that are not always named the same as the colors, but usually has something like DV-XXX-sometext.jpg

So my question basically is, how can I read this text file with PHP and parse each part into a variable so I can generate the code for it? I have no idea how to account for the different number of colours or how to add the names of the images automatically from the folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't get exactly what you want. But I think that no one could write you a complete script.

To read a file with php:

```
foreach(read("/path/to/file.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
  echo "> $line\n";
  preg_match("/(DIV|OTHER) ([0-9]++) (.*)/", $line, $matches);
  if(count($matches) == 3) {
    echo "start: ".$matches[0]."\n";
    echo "number: ".$matches[1]."\n";
    echo "text: ".$matches[2]."\n";
}
```

But all the logic stuf has to be made by you.